# Python - Convert epoch in object format to datetime

Tags: python, pandas

I'm pulling data from API that gives me date values in epoch in milliseconds, but the values are in this format:

[image]

I am trying to convert these to datetime with `pd.to_datetime(df1.loc[:, 'Curve Value'], unit='ms')`, but am getting the error

> ValueError: non convertible value 1,609,459,200,000.0000000000 with
> the unit 'ms'

I then tried to format the column into float with `df1["Curve Value"] = df["Curve Value"].astype(float)`, but get then get this error

> ValueError: could not convert string to float:
> '1,609,459,200,000.0000000000'

I've also tried various ways to remove the commas and convert to float, but get errors trying that, as well.

Comment: Have you tried doing df.read_csv(..., thousands=',') ? It will parse the number as a double/float/int

Comment: I've been reluctant to go that route. I'm hoping to find a solution that doesn't rely on writing to csv and then re-importing.

Comment: You dont have to rewrite the csv, just change the way you load the dataframe.

Comment: I changed loading the dataframe from df = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns) to df = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns, thousands=','). It threw this error TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'thousands'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit unwieldy and requires importing datetime from datetime but it works as far as I can see.

```
df['Real Time'] = df['Curve Value'].apply(lambda t: datetime.fromtimestamp(int(''.join(t.split(',')[:4]))))
```

Comment: That gets me where I needed to get. Thank you.